# esp8266 littleFS edit data on a text file

Tags: filesystems, arduino-esp8266, nodemcu

In a project I use NODEMCU ESP8266 and using webserver I can create a text file by [LittleFs](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html) and write data in it.
I use this file as a database and store user information in it.
During the project, user information changes. For example, the person's address is added. Is there a way to edit this information? Or should I create a new file and transfer the information to this new file? I didn't find anything in the LittleFs library to edit the information in the middle of the file.
For example, the initial data is like this.

```
user1 name:Jack,tel:#####
user2 name:Alex,tel:#####
```

And the edited data should be as follows.

```
user1 name:Jack,tel:#####,address:$$$$
user2 name:Alex,tel:#####
```

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: you have to create and write a new file